# Android MediaPlayer error (-19,0)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm a beginner in android development. In my App there is an mp3 file. I have used mediaPlayer class, ***But sound does not play even once***. I was searching about this error and found that this error usually occur when sound is being repeated many time which is opposite in my problem . Here is code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;
    MediaPlayer mp=null;


    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // context=this;
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.hum);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();

            };
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

}

Comment: Make sure to double check your file to ensure it is supported - http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 may be right, but it depends: are you getting a Null Pointer Exception when you call mp.start(); ?

Comment: mp3 is a supported sound format

Comment: @user3033683 yes, but sometimes you get mp3s that are container files.  These are invalid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*There was some kinda bug in emulator. I made a new emulator And Media Player error worked out*

Answer (score 0):

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.hum);
mp.prepare();

        mp.start();
```

Comment: Nope. Look at the documentation (prepare has already been called in this case): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, int)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the permission in the manifest?
[manifest permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

[sound permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

Comment: But i'm not accessing Internet for mp3